# C# Save String To Database As Geometry

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, geometry

Right now we are getting the geometry data as a string, and we need to save it to our SQL DB as a Geometry type.

Currently, I'm trying to do something that looks like this

```
String shape = "POLYGON((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))" ;
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO x (shape) values (@shape)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSql, sqlConnection);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.Text;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shape", "geometry::Parse("+shape+")");

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Every time the query executes I get an error:

> {"A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry":
>
> System.FormatException: 24114: The label geometry::Parse('POL in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type only).
>
> System.FormatException:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisTypes.ParseLabel(String input)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.Parse(SqlString s).
>
> The statement has been terminated."}

Is there a way to accomplish this natively without importing the SQL SERVER Types package? Or is the only way to achieve this to include the Nuget package and go from there?

Comment: Rather than "something that looks like this" can you provide a [mcve]? The current code wouldn't compile, and it's entirely possible that the problem is in one of the differences between your *actual* code and the code you've shown us.

Comment: Are you sure the text is what you think it is? Perhaps there's an invisible character, or that `Y` isn't the English Y ?

Comment: Note that with the edited code, you're not using the `shape` variable at all...

Comment: Right sorry about the formatting, the shape variable is getting used in the code, forgot to strip out the "" in the question.

The text is what we think it is, and the issue isn't with the text we're getting in, it's the saving of it that's the issue.

Comment: The same error gets thrown if I hardcode `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shape", "geometry::Parse('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)')"); ` into the parameter

Comment: fwiw, given the code in the question, the `shape` string variable from the first line of the code sample is **NEVER USED** again.

Comment: A string *containing* `geometry::Parse` is nothing at all like an *actual call* to `geometry::Parse`, passing it a string. Whatever else is happening, that shouldn't be embedded in the claimed "value" of the parameter.

Comment: Ahh, I see the edit. Much better.

Comment: You can't parameterize calling an sql function...

Comment: So what would be the correct way to go about calling the sql function?

Comment: @IvoBardolf you have the parse in your query, not your parameter - see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameters in SQL queries are used to prevent SQL injection - that means nothing you include in a parameter to your query will be treated as anything other than data, it won't be evaluated, so `geometry::Parse` will not run. Try something like this:

```
String shape = "POLYGON((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))" ;
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO x (shape) values (geometry::Parse(@shape))";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSql, sqlConnection);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.Text;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shape", shape);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to put the function call in the insert sql, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Fiddle for reference https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=042248a222edb980092459a928f13410